# Getting a text representation of a type

Tags: rust

I have some code which will print the `TypeId` of a variable passed in.

```
fn typeid<T: std::any::Any>(_: &T) {
    println!("{:?}", std::any::Type::of::<T>());
}
```

This works, but gives me a numeric id for the type. Is there a way to output the actual type? For example 1716249077420000607 is f64 (IIRC) or do I need to create a physical list (possibly as an enum) and output that value as part of a match construct?

Comment: I've seen that answer but get_tydesc for some reason caused the compiler to bork so wasn't sure if it was me, the call was deprecated, or something else.

Comment: The second answer works https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=de059307b1bc12ee0bd713da0284f50e&version=nightly&backtrace=0

Comment: `1716249077420000607` would be unlikely to be a `f64`. Maybe you meant `u64`?

Comment: @malbarbo - any way of getting that example to work on the stable branch?